# implementation of touch ID in our app

Tags: xamarin, touch-id

Anyone explain replyHandler and InvokeOnMainThread works in this code `enter code here`. I have copied this code form a sample project I need to implement this thing in my project

```
partial void UIButton7_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
    {
        var context = new LAContext ();

        var error = new NSError ();
        if (context.CanEvaluatePolicy (LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics,out error)) {
            var replyHandler = new LAContextReplyHandler((success, err) => {
                this.InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    if(success){
                        Console.WriteLine("You Logged in");
                    } else {
                        var errorAlertView = new UIAlertView("Login Error", err.LocalizedDescription, null, "Close");
                        errorAlertView.Show();
                    }
                });
            });
            context.EvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, "You need to login", replyHandler);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reply handler is basically a callback to manage feedback when get the result from the touch id.

InvokeOnMainThread is to allow show an ui change when gets this result back. It forces to be on the ui thread to be able to reflect an ui change.

Comment: Can you specify more on InvokeOnMainThread any resource or demo will be beneficial as I am rookie programmer

Comment: Here a reference from xamarin official documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_2_-_working_with_the_ui_thread/

Comment: By using this method how can I make It cross platform . It is showing me error  that  InvokeOnMainThread is not defined

Comment: Try using of of this xamarin plugins: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.Biometrics/ https://www.nuget.org/packages/SMS.Fingerprint/